# Can I use WSO2 Identity Server to restrict the topics a MQTT subscriber can collect?

Tags: wso2, mqtt, acl, wso2-identity-server

I want to restrict access to specific MQTT topics base on user authentication.
I want to be able to control the access of the MQTT Broker and know exactly who distributed a data.

I know you can use Access Control Lists (ACLs) to do it, but I was wondering if there was a more "Industrial Way" like with and Identity and Access Management (IAM) like WSO2 Identity Server or something else ? How can I use and IAM software to control who has the right to subscribe and publish on my MQTT broker.

Comment: If your 'Subscribe' and 'Publish' options can be exposed as Oauth2 secured REST APIs(May be via a Gateway), you can integrate Identity Server as the Oauth provider of that Gateway

Comment: Thanks a lot @NipunThathsara I found [this](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/authenticate-devices-using-mqtt) from your answer